# setTimeout in select box change event

Tags: asp.net

When I have autopostback set to true on a select box, why is the 'setTimeout' necessary in the onchange event?  Why isn't __doPostBack just called directly?

```
onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$myselect\',\'\')', 0)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbackoptions.autopostback.aspx):

The JavaScript setTimeout method is used with the _doPostBack method to ensure that the user action completes before the postback occurs.

Comment: thanks - attempted to google this but could not find the answer.  I guess I should have started at the specs.  Still strange to me that when I am hand-coding 'change' events on a select box I never have any issues with "user action" not completing

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing - and I cynically thought the evasive MSDN explanation might mean  "working around a bug in IE".

It seems this is the case! There's a race hazard in the threads handling the "use action":

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/958a24b7-775e-434b-9fd4-58f72ecbb759